# Is $AB-BA$ symmetric or skew-symmetric?

Tags: matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric matrices of same order then $AB+BA$ must be symmetric. But my question is what will happen for $AB-BA$. Is $AB-BA$ symmetric or skew-symmetric or is there no conclusion?

Comment: I think it is skew-symmetric

Comment: Just check the definition of skew symmetry. What do you get?

Comment: (AB-BA)^t=B^t A^t-A^t B^t=BA-AB=-(AB-BA) that implies it is skew-symmetric

Comment: yepp. Looks good.

Comment: Now I have another question transpose of symmetric matrix need not be symmetric matrix..plz explin me...clearly

Comment: again, check the definition. It is something you always try first.

Comment: a matrix A is symmetric if A^t=A.(A^t)^t=A=A^t..that implies transpose of symmetric matrix is symmetric

Comment: yes. looks good